# Simplest Way to Validate a Choice Made by a User

Tags: c

My code functions just fine, but I am working with a somewhat large program and would like to find a simpler/shorter way to do the same thing. I need to validate that a user is entering data that is valid according to what is being asked.

How I am doing it now:

```
while(validDoses == 0) {
    printf("Enter Recommended Shot Doses (1-255): ");
    scanf(" %d", &shotDoses);
    if(shotDoses >= 1 && shotDoses <= 255) {
        validDoses = 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("\n\033[1;31mPlease Enter a Valid Number.\033[0m\n");
    }
}
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a problem with it

Comment: is your problem that you have to do this for many different prompts? Like doses, age, weight...? Are the all numbers?

Comment: The only other thing you may want to do is check the return of `scanf`.

Comment: The `space` in `" %d"` is superfluous. The `"%d"` conversion-specifier already discards leading whitespace. In fact all conversion-specifiers EXCEPT `"%c"`, `"[...]"` and `"%n"` discard leading whitespace.

Comment: What if the user enters alphabetic characters?  You don't check the return value of scanf so you don't know if it successfully scanned a number or not.  The output variable will be uninitialized or will have the value from the previous loop so it might accidentally be a valid value.  Plus, the alphabetic characters won't be removed from the input because they weren't successfully scanned so then you have an infinite loop.  You do need to check the return value.

Comment: The shorter way is to write a function that accepts a prompt and a variable by reference.  Then when you want to get user input you just have a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write an indefinite loop, and only break out when a valid input is provided.

```
for (;;) {
    printf("Enter Recommended Shot Doses (1-255): ");
    scanf("%d", &shotDoses);

    if (shotDoses >= 1 && shotDoses <= 255) break;
    
    printf("\n\033[1;31mPlease Enter a Valid Number.\033[0m\n");
}
```

Worth noting that we haven't checked the return value of `scanf`.

```
for (;;) {
    printf("Enter Recommended Shot Doses (1-255): ");

    if (scanf("%d", &shotDoses) == 1 && 
        shotDoses >= 1 && shotDoses <= 255) break;
    
    printf("\n\033[1;31mPlease Enter a Valid Number.\033[0m\n");
}
```

Comment: Good approach, but you should also save and check the return against a manual `EOF` as that is a valid way for users to cancel input. (`ctrl + d` Linux, `ctrl + z` windows). Simple enough, `int rtn = scanf("%d", &shotDoses);` -- then perform each of the tests needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you define

```
#define p printf
#define s scanf
#define E "Enter Recommended Shot Doses (1-255): "
#define D shotDoses
#define v validDoses
#define N "\n\033[1;31mPlease Enter a Valid Number.\033[0m\n"
#define w while
#define e else
#define i if
#define z " %d"
```

Then it can be very short.

```
w(v==0){ p(E); s(z, &D); i(D >= 1 && D <= 255) v = 1; e p(z);}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness... But worth the nod just for sheer creativity!

Comment: It's short, as long as you don't count all of the preprocessor stuff. ;)

Comment: should be `e p(N)`